# Yii Display data from dataprovider of 2 models

Tags: php, yii

How can I display "arrendatario_nombre" using a dataprovider in a Clistview

```
$dataProviderContratos = new CActiveDataProvider(ZfContratos::model(), array(
            'keyAttribute'=>'zf_contrato_id',
            'criteria'=>array(
                'order' => 'contrato_fecha_ini',
                'select' => 't.*, arr.arrendatario_nombre as arrendatario_nombre',
                'join' => 'LEFT JOIN zf_arrendatarios arr ON arr.arrendatario_id = t.zf_arrendatarios_arrendatario_id',
                'condition'=>'zf_inmuebles_inmueble_id=-1',
            ),
        ));
```

I tried:

```
$data->arrendatario_nombre
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Yii relations for this purpose,
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship

In your `ZfContratos` model file use the following and then you can call `$data->arrendatario_nombre`

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'arrendatario_nombre' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'zf_arrendatarios', 'zf_arrendatarios_arrendatario_id'),
        );
    }
```

Once this is declared in the model file you can use `$data->arrendatario_nombre` and also in any other place place you load the Zfcontratos `model`

Comment: With "echo CHtml::encode($data->arrendatario_nombre" the error is: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Comment: $data->arrendatario_nombre loads the model itself you cannot print it directly with CHtml::encode .. you should use an attribute from the model(table) for example name is defined in zf_arrendatarios then you can use CHtml::encode($data->arrendatario_nombre->name)